# no TF between base_link and map in multiple-robots in gazebo

Tags: gazebo, simulation, turtlebot

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello everyone,

I want to simulate two robots(  turtlebots ) in gazebo instead of stage_ros. I use the model described in [here](http://answers.ros.org/question/41433/multiple-robots-simulation-and-navigation/), and the TF problem(  no transform from map to odom in amcl.`Timed out waiting for transform from robot_0/base_link to map to become available before running costmap, tf error: . canTransform returned after 0.1 timeout was 0.1.`) occurs. There is also another problem [here](http://answers.ros.org/question/227728/multiple-robots-simulation-in-stage-with-amcl-navigation/), the author could add two or more robots in stage_ros but when I change the code to gazebo(  simply change the world model , add gazebo_ros, change the global_frame_id,etc  ), the TF problem still stay.

The topic flow is below.
[image: image description]

In this experiment, I only add one robot with `tf_prefix` and `ns`, as I think if one robot is ok, than two is also.

I also try to delete the `ns` and `tf_prefix`, than the single robot could work and the topic is here.
[image: image description]

Could you help me, please..

Thanks first.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/250657/no-tf-between-base_link-and-map-in-multiple-robots-in-gazebo/) by [wsAndy](https://answers.ros.org/users/21662/wsandy/) on ROS Answers with karma: 224 on 2016-12-23

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I think it is because you accidentally look for you map in the namespace.
In the launch file for you nodes you should look whether your nodes subscribe to "map" or "/map".
"/map" is the global topic for the map which you want to use as the map_server should not be launched in a namespace.
From the error it seems that the issue is with amcl, so I would probably look in the amcl launch file and change "map" to "/map".
When you only write "map" amcl tries to subscribe to "robot_0/map" topic because of the namespace, but as map_server is global the topic does not exist.

---

Originally posted by [FOXTER](https://answers.ros.org/users/26976/foxter/) with karma: 153 on 2016-12-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [apletta](https://answers.ros.org/users/43189/apletta/) on 2019-06-24**:
Is there a way to do a similar thing for the move_base node? I have nearly the same problem as described above and with the tf_prefix can only get "/map" connected to the amcl node, not the move_base node. I've tried remap from="map" to="/map" but nothing seems to change. When I experiment without the namespace the remapping has an effect but with the namespace it seems it doesn't. Thoughts?